# Artifactory retention to have max number of builds

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am using Artifactory open source version with Jenkins.We push the builds from Jenkins to Artifactory with build info as below.

```
 def server = Artifactory.server('Artifactory_Server')  
 def targetArtifact = "Repo/${RepoName}/${archivePath}.zip" 

                        def uploadSpec = """{
                        "files": [
                                {
                                    "pattern": "${archivePath}.zip",            
                                    "target":  "${targetArtifact}"                              
                                }
                            ]
                            }"""    
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 2, maxDays: 2, doNotDiscardBuilds: ["5"], deleteBuildArtifacts: true                         

buildInfo.env.capture = true        

server.upload(uploadSpec)
server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
```

The builds not getting removed or deleted upon publishing build info to Artifactory server. What should be done to remove the builds

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who finds this question, I've heard build retention settings only work in the pro version of Artifactory. I haven't verified it not working in free, but I have verified the following jenkinsfile works as expected when used with pro Artifactory:

```
node {
    // Obtain an Artifactory server instance, defined in Jenkins --> Manage:
    def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID
    def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()

    stage ('Collect env vars') {
        // By default the filter is configured to exclude "*password*,*secret*,*key*"
        buildInfo.env.filter.addInclude("*")
        buildInfo.env.filter.addExclude("DONT_COLLECT*")

        withEnv(['DO_COLLECT_FOO=BAR', 'DONT_COLLECT_FOO=BAR']) {
            buildInfo.env.collect()
        }
    }

    stage ('Access build info env vars') {
        echo buildInfo.env.vars['DO_COLLECT_FOO']   //BAR
        echo buildInfo.env.vars['DONT_COLLECT_FOO'] //null
    }

    stage ('Set build retention') {
        buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 1, maxDays: 2, doNotDiscardBuilds: ["3"], deleteBuildArtifacts: true
    }

    stage ('Publish build info') {
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
}
```

This is from the [JFrog examples github page](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/vars-build-retention-example/Jenkinsfile)

Another important point would be that these retention rules appear to be for metadata (the json files that are stored in [artifactory-build-info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration#BuildIntegration-BuildInfoRepository)), not build artefacts.

It may also be worth checking that the user configured within the Artifactory plugin has sufficient permissions within Artifactory to do the clean up. This can be done in Artifactory by going to:
Artifacts -> Artifactory Repository Browser -> 
artifactory-build-info -> Effective Permissions

Answer (score 0):

At first I also thought it doesn't work, but then I figured out that the artifacts (**deleteBuildArtifacts: true**) and the build-info only gets deleted if you upload a new build-info (trigger jenkins job again).

I used the following pipeline to test it:

```
#!groovy

node('master') {
    sh ("touch foo${BUILD_NUMBER}.txt")
    
    def server = Artifactory.server('artifactory')
    def uploadSpec = """{
            "files": [
                {
                    "pattern": "foo${BUILD_NUMBER}.txt",
                    "target": "<repo-name>"
                }
            ]
        }"""

    def buildInfo = server.upload spec: uploadSpec
    buildInfo.retention maxDays: 1, deleteBuildArtifacts: true // this will remove all artifacts + build-info older than 1 day (retrigger job)
    //buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 1, deleteBuildArtifacts: true // this will only keep 1 artifact + build-info
    server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
}
```

as descirbed here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-TriggeringBuildRetention

Artifactory version: Commerical 7.10.2